# Python - selenium cmd line browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I write simple script which open website and check one text and if text==text send email.
This script work very well on windows because I use chrome and chrome driver, but I want to run this script on linux server without desktop. 
Do I can run selenium with comandline browser links or other? Maybe is other solution?

UPDATE
I finally instaled google chrome, but now I have this:

```
 File "script.py", line 47, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/share/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

**I have installed:**

- ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39
- Google Chrome 83.0.4103.97

Answer (score 0):

You can try headless browsers: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

This will run your script without opening an actual browser window.

Comment: I getting this error: `
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/webdriver_manager/chrome.py", line 4, in <module>
    from webdriver_manager import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/webdriver_manager/utils.py", line 58
    log(f"Trying to download new driver from {url}")
`

Comment: You still need to have appropriate `chrome` and its compatible `chromedriver` version installed on your linux server

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/share/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
> ```

You need to pass the location of the chromedriver with the extention ".exe" so it will be

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/share/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: But I have this chromedriver* not exe? When I run ./chromedriver - ChromeDriver was started successfully.